# не работает разметка GRID

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Не понимаю почему не работает grid-template-areas

```css
.wrapper{
display: grid;
height: 100vh;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-areas:
"header header header"
"menu content content"
"footer footer footer";
grid-gap: 10px;
margin: 0;
}

.wrapper div{
   background: gold;
}

#PageHead{
   grid-area: header;
 }
#PageMenu{
    grid-area: menu;
 }
#PageContent{
     grid-area: content;
 }
#PageFooter{
     grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id=”PageHead”>Head</div>
    <div id=”PageMenu”>Menu</div>
    <div id=”PageContent”>Content</div>
    <div id=”PageFooter”>Footer</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Советую для таких целей использовать flex, если у вас нет цели делать сайт для IE ниже 10го. На флексах делается всё не менее просто и прекрасно работает. Тут можете ознакомиться: https://html5.by/blog/flexbox/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <div id=”PageHead”>Head</div>
> ```

Когда копипастишь код, кавычки выпрямлять надо:

```
<div id="PageHead">Head</div>
```

Всё работает:

```css
.wrapper{
display: grid;
height: 100vh;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-areas:
"header header header"
"menu content content"
"footer footer footer";
grid-gap: 10px;
margin: 0;
}

.wrapper div{
   background: gold;
}

#PageHead{
   grid-area: header;
 }
#PageMenu{
    grid-area: menu;
 }
#PageContent{
     grid-area: content;
 }
#PageFooter{
     grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="PageHead">Head</div>
    <div id="PageMenu">Menu</div>
    <div id="PageContent">Content</div>
    <div id="PageFooter">Footer</div>
</div>
```

В принципе, вот так оно бы тоже работало, но это жесть:

```css
.wrapper{
display: grid;
height: 100vh;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-areas:
"header header header"
"menu content content"
"footer footer footer";
grid-gap: 10px;
margin: 0;
}

.wrapper div{
   background: gold;
}

#”PageHead”{
   grid-area: header;
 }
#”PageMenu”{
    grid-area: menu;
 }
#”PageContent”{
     grid-area: content;
 }
#”PageFooter”{
     grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id=”PageHead”>Head</div>
    <div id=”PageMenu”>Menu</div>
    <div id=”PageContent”>Content</div>
    <div id=”PageFooter”>Footer</div>
</div>
```